# Scoped Services within ServiceBus Event Handle

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, access-token, azureservicebus

I am in the process of creating a system that will subscribe to a topic inside Azure Service Bus and handle the messages.

The handling will then involve a HTTP call.

https://damienbod.com/2019/04/23/using-azure-service-bus-queues-with-asp-net-core-services/

I have amended the blog code to something like the below

```
services.AddSingleton<IServiceBusTopicSubscription, ServiceBusTopicSubscription>();
services.AddScoped<IProcessData, ProcessData>();
services.AddScoped<IExternalRestSystem, ExternalRestSystem>();
```

Process Class

```
public class ProcessData : IProcessData
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IExternalRestSystem _externalRestSystem;

    public ProcessData(IConfiguration configuration, IExternalRestSystem externalRestSystem)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _externalRestSystem = externalRestSystem;
    }
    public async Task Process(MyPayload myPayload)
    {
        //do work, create data entity, this is called from the servicebus event handler
        await externalRestSystem.SendToApi(customData);
    }
}
```

ExternalRestSystemClass

```
public class ExternalRestSystemClass: IExternalRestSystemClass
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;

    public ExternalRestSystemClass(IConfiguration configuration, ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
    {
         _configuration= configuration;
         _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
    }

    public async Task SendToApi(Data customData)
    {
        //get scope from configuration
        string accessToken = tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopesToAccessDownstreamApi);
       //httpcreation
       //flurl with oauth from token acquired, postasync data
    }
}
```

Now I understand the issue I have, but I am unsure how to resolve it. My ServiceBus event handler is singleton, and as I understand it, will always be the case. My classes that I wish to then be used to read the data, store it somewhere, then send a confirmation to an API of some other data need to be scoped. I guess created for each message received and disposed of after. ITokenAcqusition is used for Web API calls to each other, and infact my system does have controllers for administration of some other data needed, but I cannot use ITokenAqusition because IServiceProvider will be disposed of.

However I am unsure how to go about what I need to do. I am thinking nServiceBus would help but do not want to go down this route unless it will.

Comment: Good question. Sample app (eshopcontainer) of Microsoft team uses event handler of receiver (they forgot session etc but anyway). But they do not now anything about "service scope".  Sample application seems work well but... I use scoped service event handler block for be sure. I am wondering someone give right answer. ;) good luck.